# Deta Space - Is it possible to modify the default version of Node that runs on a Micro?

Tags: node.js, space

I'm trying to build a cloud application on Deta Space (https://deta.space/) and I'm having some trouble with the Node version. I want to use Node18, which works fine on my local machine (`$ space dev`), but when I upload it to the cloud (`$ space push`) it gives me an error during building process, saying Micro uses Node16 and minumum Node18 is required.

My application has two Micros: one for the frontend (GatsbyJS V5), where is the issue, and one for the backend (Python). This is my Spacefile:

```
# Spacefile Docs: https://go.deta.dev/docs/spacefile/v0
v: 0
micros:
  - name: frontend
    src: ./frontend/
    engine: static
    primary: true
    commands:
      - npm run build
    serve: public
    dev: npm run develop
  - name: backend
    src: ./backend/
    engine: python3.9
    dev: uvicorn main:app --reload
    run: uvicorn main:app
    path: api
    primary: false
```

Is there a way to specify the Node version for the frontend micro? Or do I have to use Node16?.

I'd like to know whether I can specify or install a new Node version in the Micros.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space only supports Node.js 16 based on [their documentation](https://deta.space/docs/en/build/quick-starts/node/). You'll need to use v16 locally for now.